# Problem with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I have one activity with that launches another activity that has a EditText-view. When the user clicks the "Back" button I want the string in this edit text view to be returned but I can't get it to work. I tried to implement a button (test purpose) and running my code and then it works.

In the activity that launches the other one:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (REQUEST_CODE_COMMENT == requestCode) {
            if (RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
                Toast.makeText(this, data.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

The activity with the edit text view (I want this to work):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("hfldskajfkj" + commentEditText.getText().toString()));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);   
}
```

But the resultCode is 0 (RESULT_CANCELLED) when i log it.

Comment: Are you working against android 1.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
}
```

Thats the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` *(also mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29))*. This means your activity gets finished (with the default code `RESULT_CANCELLED`) before your other code gets invoked. Removing `super.onBackPressed()` and adding `finish()` on the bottom should fix this.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, ofcourse! When I call super.onBackPressed() I finish() the activity before coming to the next lines.

Comment: Correct. Also to mention (at least read it please): [Don't take over the BACK key unless you absolutely need to](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html#taking_over_back_key). Pressing back isn't for navigation only, it's kind of a cancel-action. In this case it means save/ok. This may confuse users, they rely on the correct function. I'd suggest to build a dedicated ok-button instead. :)

Comment: Okey. I will change it. Would you add a save button or prompt the user when he/she clicks the Back button?

Comment: I think a dedicated save button is the better way here and often used in android apps (e.g. when firing the "take picture" intent most camera apps do it this way). The prompt would be ok, but it annoys me as a user when I'm not immediately taken back (e.g. astro file manager with it's "press back twice to exit this app") - but well, this is my personal opinion.

Comment: I understand. Thank you, much appriciated:)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this: The API says:

> public void onBackPressed ()              Since: API Level 5
>
> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default 
>   implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do 
>   whatever you want.

And when you call super.onBackPressed() all the references to the particular activity are cleared. Hence the particular data is not added. Try the same code inserted in OnClickListener of a button. That should work

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the Android UI guidelines it says you should not have explicit “save” buttons. In this case, the answer is simple: don’t bother checking if the result code is RESULT_OK, always use the last value of the EditText widget regardless.